# Gunicorn Nginx Django static files: images not shown

Tags: django, nginx, django-staticfiles

I've been digging through articles and posts about this subject but can't seem to get my **images** to load. For some reason the **CSS** on my pages seems to load just fine.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

also I tried

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/myname/'
```

template

```
<img src="{% static 'picture.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid">
```

NGINX

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django_project

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/myname/static/;
    }
}
```

directories

```
/var/www/myname
└── static
    └── admin
        ├── css
        │   ├── styles1.css
        │   └── styles2.css
        ├── images
        │   ├── picture.jpg
        │   └── python.jpg
        └── js
            └── scripts.js

/home/myname/myprojectdir
├── django_project     
│   ├── django_project 
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── etc            
│   ├── index                   
│   │   ├── migrations          
│   │   │   └── __pycache__     
│   │   ├── __pycache__         
│   │   └── templates           
│   │       └── index           
│   │           └── backups     
│   ├── __pycache__             
│   └── static                  
│       ├── admin               
│       │   ├── css             
│       │   │   └── vendor      
│       │   │       └── select2 
│       │   ├── fonts           
│       │   ├── images          
│       │   │   └── gis         
│       │   ├── img             
│       │   │   └── gis         
│       │   └── js              
│       │       ├── admin       
│       │       └── vendor      
│       │           ├── jquery  
│       │           ├── select2 
│       │           │   └── i18n
│       │           └── xregexp 
│       ├── images
│       └── index
│           ├── css
│           ├── images
│           └── js
├── myname_env
│   ├── bin
│   └── lib
│       └── python3.10
│           └── site-packages
└── static
    └── admin
        ├── css
        │   └── vendor
        │       └── select2
        ├── fonts
        ├── img
        │   └── gis
        └── js
            ├── admin
            └── vendor
                ├── jquery
                ├── select2
                │   └── i18n
                └── xregexp
```

I've tried installing the static files in other directories, etc, to see what works but I'm not having any luck whatsoever. I had the static files in the project but after reading that's not a good practice I put them into var/www.

Comment: Based on your nginx config and folder structure the only `picture.jpg` is under `/admin/images/` directory. If this is it then the url should be `{% static '/admin/images/picture.jpg' %}`.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I appreciate the clarification on this. I'll give this a shot when I can. I circumvented the problem by hosting the images externally on imgur. In the end, probably for the best, but I'll still try your solution to solidify my understanding of how Django works.

Answer (score 0):

can you add this into nginx conf and try:

```
location /images/ {
        alias /var/www/myname/static/images;
    }
```